# xUnit Project in VS2019

Tags: c#, xunit, visual-studio-2019

I want to add a new xUnit Test Project but i can't find it in the dialog. What's the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You must select this one and then you have xUnit testing.

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot in english?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the corresponding [workload](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/visual-studio-workloads/) (*.NET Core*):

**xUnit Test Project** is a **.NET Core** project template, which is included in the **.NET Core cross-platform development** workload.

You can install additional workloads to customize your Visual Studio installation with the *Visual Studio Installer*, which you can start via `Install more tools and features` from the *Project-Wizard*, via `Visual Studio > Tools > Get Tools and Features...`, or as described here: [Modify Visual Studio by adding or removing workloads and components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio)

Answer (score 3):

@Deilan:

[image: Universal Windows Platform Development]

BUT! Actually you'd install xUnit via NuGet. VisualStudio -> Tools - NuGet Package Manager -> Manage NuGet Packages for Solution ...

[image: NuGet. xUnit]